# Missing design IP modules on testbench error(VIVADO)

Tags: verilog, vivado

While simulating a design wrapper file. I am getting a error messages as seen:[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWdWW.jpg). Despite all the modules names are correct in the wrapper file Why i am getting these errors. Can you help me about that.
Thanks i advance
wrapper file = [wrapper file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpjc6.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please click wrapper file. code is available in the link

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is because the IPs you have included have not generated their wrapper HDL files. Right-click the IP in the sources tab and click "Generate Output Products". I think "Generate Block Design" in the left tab is also supposed to do this.

In my projects, I can expand the IP in the sources tab as shown below to see its generated products. Since that is not available to you, as far as i can see from the image, I presume this is the reason.

[image]